# How do I check which javascript TypedArray is greater?

Tags: javascript, browser, typed-arrays

I'm trying to compare Uint8Arrays and figure out which one is greater.  The problem is that when I do it like this:

```js
let u8a = new Uint8Array(100);
TextEncode.encodeInto("randomString", u8a);

let u8b = new Uint8Array(100);
TextEncode.encodeInto("differentRandomString", u8b);

if(u8a > u8b){
  console.log("the first one is greater");
}
```

They are not compared in the same way as if I had done :

```js
if("randomString" > "differentRandomString"){
  console.log("the first one is greater");
}
```

This has implications on how items are sorted in any comparison function I create.

How can I make sure that the Uint8Arrays are compared as if they were strings without TextDecoding them into actual strings first?  I'm not sure if this is a stupid question or not.

Comment: You could compare them byte-by-byte, but the utf8 byte encoding of strings is not how strings are normally compared character-by-character. What's wrong with converting them to strings?

Comment: Comparing them as strings is slower, or rather, converting them to strings then comparing them is slower.

Comment: Given you haven't implemented the bytewise comparison yet, how do you know? Are you saying your current code runs *too* slow (for something)?

Comment: That's not what I'm saying and I'm not sure how asking that helps answer my initial question.  I'm saying that given a string TextEncoded to an array of bytes, when sorting them with a comparison function I'd like to end up with the same ordering as if I had compared them when they were strings.  I just want to know if there is a way to do it while they're still byte arrays.